# How do you set a cookie in a Facebook Tab or Canvas App?

Tags: facebook, cookies, canvas

I know that Firefox and Chrome handle this already and using a P3P header for IE will allow setting cookies from the server side. I want to know if there is anyway to set a cookie in the Facebook App that will work in Safari if the user has never visited your site?

I need to be able to set a cookie for session management to know whether my users are authenticated or have any data in the session. This works perfectly in all browsers except Safari when the user has never visited the site because of Safari's "third party cookie" policy.

I thought it would work because Facebook renders the iframe as a POST to your app but it appears that it does not as my App will not set the cookie in Safari.

I a hoping others have run into this problem and can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: I use session cookies quite often. the p3p header is set to 

CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"

 and it works fine on all browsers that we support (IE 8 & above, Chrome, FF & safari.)

Are your follow up calls to the same domain as the one from where your Facebook App iFrame is loaded?

Comment: Shreeni: I was pretty sure that Safari does not respect P3P headers but I tried your P3P compact policy anyway and it did not work. My cookie was still not set. You should try this on your app by firing up Safari and resetting it so everything is cleared out. Then go straight to your app without going to your website at all and see if you also have the problem.

Comment: We run a bunch of apps and all depend on basic session cookies to get us going and pretty much all of them are tested and seemed to be working. I will check again and let you know.

Comment: @TravisChase I don't suppose you found a solution for this in the end? I'm in the same boat as you right now.